# In QCustomPlot how do you draw both a line graph and bar chart for the same data in realtime?

Tags: c++, qt, graph, qcustomplot

I am using `QtCreator` and have installed the `QCustomPlot` library in my project. I want to be able to draw both a line graph and bar chart for the same data. The data is held in an array which is constantly updated by another function - hence, **how do you create a realtime line graph and bar chart on the same axes?**

This is the statements that set the x and y coordinates of points.

```
QVector<double> x(140), y(140);
for (int q=5; i<145; i+5)
{
    x[q] = q;
    y[q] = GraphReadings[((q/5)*2)+2];
}
```

Comment: Not sure  how you want the bar chart to look like, but you may have have to create/populate a `QCPBars` every time you handle replotting and then add it as a Plottable to the custom plot widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example on the QCustomPlot tutorials site for this: http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/styleddemo

This example shows a line graph and bar graph on the same axes, however doesn't share exactly the same data but the general idea of how to do it is there.